# how can i get this type of view in android?

Tags: android, canvas

How can i get this type of view in my layout ?

[image: How can i get this type of view in my layout ?]

//my DrawView Class

```
public class DrawViewEdit extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    JSONObject layersJsonObject;

    private void init() {
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    }

    public DrawViewEdit(Context context, JSONObject layersJsonObject) {
        super(context);
        this.layersJsonObject = layersJsonObject;
        init();
    }

    public DrawViewEdit(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public DrawViewEdit(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(500, 800);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        try {
                canvas.drawLine(Float.parseFloat("" + Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("x1")) * 1.5),
                        Float.parseFloat("" + Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("y1")) * 1.5),
                        Float.parseFloat("" + Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("x2")) * 1.5),
                        Float.parseFloat("" + Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("y2")) * 1.5), paint);
                canvas.drawLine(Float.parseFloat("" + Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("x2")) * 1.5),
                        Float.parseFloat("" + Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("y2")) * 1.5),
                        Float.parseFloat("" + Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("x3")) * 1.5),
                        Float.parseFloat("" + Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("y3")) * 1.5), paint);
                canvas.drawLine(Float.parseFloat("" + Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("x3")) * 1.5),
                        Float.parseFloat("" + Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("y3")) * 1.5),
                        Float.parseFloat("" + Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("x4")) * 1.5),
                        Float.parseFloat("" + Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("y4")) * 1.5), paint);
                canvas.drawLine(Float.parseFloat("" + Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("x4")) * 1.5),
                        Float.parseFloat("" + Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("y4")) * 1.5),
                        Float.parseFloat("" + Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("x1")) * 1.5),
                        Float.parseFloat("" + Integer.parseInt(layersJsonObject.getString("y1")) * 1.5), paint);

            } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

i Have tried using canvas and frameLayout but not getting proper result so can anyone tell me how to get this type of view ?
[I got this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvJvd.png)

[but i want this type of view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PbdJ.png)

Comment: post your code.

Comment: If you ask as the query code, you will benefit more

Comment: @pskink do you know the answer of my question ?